# The information i put into my registration form will not be entered into the mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

So when i put the information into my registration form that information wont go to the phpmyadmin database...This is the code:

This is the index.php file:

```
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
   include 'dbh.inc.php';
   include 'comments.inc.php';
   session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<!--Ovo je za login -->
<?php
   echo "<form method='POST' action='".getLogin($conn)."'>
      <input type='text' name='uid'>
      <input type='password' name='pwd'>
      <button type='submit' name='loginSubmit'>Login</button>
    </form>";
     echo "<form method='POST' action='".userLogout()."'>
      <button type='submit' name='logoutSubmit'>Log out</button>
    </form>";

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        echo "You are logged in";

    } else {
        echo "You are NOT logged in!";
    }
?>
<!-- Ovo je za register -->
<?php

echo "<form action='signup.php' method='POST'>
      <input type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username'><br>
    <input type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'><br>
    <button type='submit'>SIGN UP</button>
</form>";
?>

<br><br>
<!-- OVDE SE ZAVRSAVA -->

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N6sB0-jKS6c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<?php
echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
     <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
     <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
     <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
     <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
</form>";

getComments($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the comments.inc.php file

```
<?php
function setComments($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])){
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}

function getComments($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<div class='comment-box'><p>";
          echo $row['uid']."<br>";
          echo $row['date']."<br>";
          echo nl2br($row['message']);
    echo "</p>

    <form class='delete-form' method='POST' action='".deleteComments($conn)."'>
                 <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$row['cid']."'>               
                 <button type='submit' name='commentDelete'>Delete</button>
             </form>

            <form class='edit-form' method='POST' action='editcomment.php'>
                 <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$row['cid']."'>
                 <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$row['uid']."'>
                 <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".$row['date']."'>
                 <input type='hidden' name='message' value='".$row['message']."'>
                 <button>Edit</button>
             </form>
    </div>";

    }
}

function editComments($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])){
        $cid = $_POST['cid'];
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "UPDATE comments SET message='$message' WHERE cid='$cid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

function deleteComments($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['commentDelete'])){
        $cid = $_POST['cid'];

        $sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE cid='$cid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

function getLogin($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])) {
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$pwd'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
              $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
               header("Location: index.php?loginsuccess");
               exit();
         }  
     }else{
         header("Location: index.php?loginfailed");
         exit();

     }  
    }
}

function userLogout() {
    if (isset($_POST['logoutSubmit'])) {
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

This is the signup.php file

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php';

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (uid, pwd)
VALUES ('$uid', '$pwd')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location: index.php");
```

The dbh.php file just for connecting the database

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "logintest");

if (!$conn){
     die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

//

<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
   include 'dbh.inc.php';
   include 'comments.inc.php';
?>
```

And the editcomment.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
$cid = $_POST['cid'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

echo "<form method='POST' action='".editComments($conn)."'>
     <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$cid."'>
     <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$uid."'>
     <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".$date."'>
     <textarea name='message'>".$message."</textarea><br>
     <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Edit</button>
</form>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Ok so I think the problem may lie in the index.php file where the register form is placed or in the signup.php file but I do not know how to fix It.

Comment: Please read how to provide a [mcve] and reduce these code blocks above to show us only the problematic part. E.g. CSS is totally irrelevant when you have problems with PHP and MySQL, but your MySQL database schema would be useful. Regarding your problem, I'd suggest you to try outputting the MySQL errors and also, check if the POST data arrives in your PHP file before running MySQL insert.

Comment: Also, take a look at prepared statements

Comment: Hello sorry for the late response,I did try echo-ing out the information in my signup.php file and I get an error: "Warning: include(dbh.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\commentsection\signup.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'dbh.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\commentsection\signup.php on line 3
pepi123" I do not know whats the problem because it cleary is written out: "include 'dbh.php';"

Comment: Sorry i realized the problem,Ok so I did echo out the code and It showed an error that the dbh.php file didnt exist then I realized that I actually named the folder "dbh.inc.php" so I changed that and It worked,now I have one last problem,when i click on signup it does sign up the new user and when i use it in the login it works,but for some reason the data doesnt show up in phpmyadmin

Comment: Btw my schema is commentsection-->user,comments those are my two tables which user has the id,uid and pwd

Comment: Never mind i managed to solve the issue,the issue was in my database schema!